# I was trying to display the data using tkinter.But suddenly this occured

Tags: python, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I was trying to give the data to the gui using tkinter

```
def get_country_data():
      name=textfield.get()
      url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/'+name
      html_data = get_html_data(url)
      dta = BeautifulSoup(html_data.text, 'lxml')
      covi = dta.find("div", class_="content-inner").find_all('div', id='maincounter-wrap')
      data = ""
      for block in covi:
           text = block.find('h1').get_text()  #this is where the error is occuring
           count = block.find('span').get_text()
           data = data + text + count + '\n'
      mainlabel['text']=data
```

And this is where I am connecting tkinter to the data

```
    gbtn=tk.Button(root,text='Get Data',font=f,relief='solid',command=get_country_data)
    gbtn.pack()
```

and i  am getting the error

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I have very little knowledge about tkinter.I dont know how it works.Please help me to sort it oout

Answer (score 1):

The error is not to do with Tkinter, it is to do with your `get_country_data` function.

`block.find('h1')` is returning a NoneType object, hence when you call `.get_text()` it throws the `AttributeError`.

Comment: So what is the solution..?

Comment: Solution is to debug your `get_country_data()` function and figure out why your `block.find()` call is returning a None type -- what is `h1`, does it exist as a block? What is the state of `covi` after your call to `dta.find` add print statements and understand what your code is doing -- figuring things like this out yourself will teach you far more than copying someone's solution